# Print String[] In textView on Android

Tags: android, textview

I've a String[] and i'd like print all positions this String in textview

code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < something.length; i++) {
  myMsg.setText(something[i]);
}
```

but in textview, only last position is being displayed.

Answer (score 3):

because you are replacing your text in your `textview` at every iteration by calling `setText`.

use `append` instead. like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < something.length; i++) {
  myMsg.append(something[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use `append` for any reason. You can use Concatenation Operator `+`.

```
myMsg = ""; // initialize String to to empty
for (int i =0  ; i< something.length ; i++){
   myMsg+= something[i];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too, If you dont want to use loop.

```
myMsg.setText(Arrays.toString(something));
```

or without commas and brackets

```
myMsg.setText(Arrays.toString(something).replaceAll("[,\\[\\]]+", " "));
```

or without commas and brackets and removed trailing and leading whitespace

```
myMsg.setText(Arrays.toString(something).replaceAll("[,\\[\\]]+", " ").trim());
```

Hope it helps :)